# Footnote ending on another page

Tags: footnotes

I have added several footnotes in my text, but one behaves wrongly. It starts at page 4 and ends on page 5. Don't know why! It's long 6 rows.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4widepaper]{article}
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{1mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item BLA BLA BLA\footnote{Long explanation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Don't know if the above example is useful. I think that my case is in some way unique, but it would be too long to report all the code used here (see this image to visualize the issue).

[image: Text Example]

NB - In my code, there is no space between the word and the command `\footnote{}`.

Is there a way to force LaTeX to end up the footnote paragraph on the correct page?

Comment: it's clear in the linked picture that there  is only 5 rows left in the page  and  your footnote is of 6.

Comment: @touhami Can I do something to change this and solve the issue?

Comment: you  can   try (becaerful) `\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}\footnote{...}`

Comment: @touhami Thank man! Now it put all the footnote on one page. Actually, it overlaps with the page number, so I will not use this trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
```

http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-splitfoot.html